# Unable to create ListItems with 'Objects' using Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a SharePoint ListItem using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/sharepoint-concept-overview).

The methods I use to POST/PATCH `ListItems` are working unless I apply these methods to a list that contain objects (like Groups, Users or even Images).

In my examples, I'll be posting, patching or getting from `/beta/sites/root/lists/1231231231234/items/4/fields`.

**SharePoint ListItem**

```
{
  "@odata.context":
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('root')/lists('1234123412341234')/items('4')/fields/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"123412341234,18\"",
  "Title": "Test Title",
  "description": "Some random description",
  "assignedGroups": [
    {
      "LookupId": 7818,
      "LookupValue": "7818",
      "Email": "DemoGroep@12341234.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    {
      "LookupId": 7822,
      "LookupValue": "7822",
      "Email": "TestDemo@12341234.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  ],
  "startDate": "2018-05-15T07:00:00Z",
  "endDate": "2018-08-18T07:00:00Z",
  "alwaysAvailable": false,
  "id": "4",
  "ContentType": "Item",
  "Modified": "2018-05-17T13:27:21Z",
  "Created": "2018-04-03T09:34:49Z",
  "AuthorLookupId": "7688",
  "EditorLookupId": "5222",
  "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
  "Attachments": false,
  "Edit": "",
  "LinkTitleNoMenu": "Test123123",
  "LinkTitle": "Test123123",
  "ItemChildCount": "0",
  "FolderChildCount": "0",
  "_ComplianceFlags": "",
  "_ComplianceTag": "",
  "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
  "_ComplianceTagUserId": "",
  "AppEditorLookupId": "25"
}
```

**Working example** (Note: This works because I update a simple field like 'Title' which is of type String)

```
{
   Title: "SomeNewTitle"
}
```

**Not working Example** (returns `400 'The request is malformed or incorrect.'`)

```
{
  assignedGroups: [{"Email": "Test1003@12341234o.onmicrosoft.com"}]
}
```

I tried multiple kinds of objects here but it never works.. even empty arrays (to clear group memberships) is returning `400` status.

I have a feeling that this is a limitation/bug in the Graph API

Comment: I'm not familiar, try "assignedGroups" in quotes? Not sure if this will work because Title is not in quotes and seems to work

Comment: Good try but did not work ;)

Comment: It looks like in your SharePoint `listItem` the `assignedGroups` array contains three fields. Try including `lookUpId` as well as `lookUpValue` along with your email.

Comment: Tried, no luck..

Comment: Oh okay, try the same patch you have in the post with `{ }` instead of `[ ]`

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a known issue with Microsoft Graph's SharePoint API. There is a [UserVoice request to fix this](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32293726-support-sharepoint-lookup-fields-when-creating-lis), it could absolutely use more votes.

Comment: Thanks, bummer though ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Try the PATCH body like this:

```
//PATCH
{
  assignedGroups: {"Email": "Test1003@StichtingNuovo.onmicrosoft.com"}
}
```

Because in the `listItem` it is returning an array of `assignedGroups` but you are only updating one. If you needed to update multiple I believe the call would be:

```
//PATCH
{
  assignedGroups: [{"Email": "Test1003@StichtingNuovo.onmicrosoft.com"},
                   {"Email": "AnotherEmail@microsoft.com"}
                  ]
}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm providing an array with 1 group. This should change memberships from 3 groups to 1

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. Can't find anything in documentation either.